# unable to load kinesis native library when using aws Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

Am trying to upload lambda function which within I use kinesis video streaming
I can use it locally because I can link native library `"libKinesisVideoProducerJNI.so"`when I upload it to AWS lambda I keep getting the error

```
WARN / KinesisVideo: Unsatisfied link error. Directly loading native library .so.

22:19:11
WARN / KinesisVideo: Unsatisfied link error. Directly loading native library .dylib.

22:19:11
WARN / KinesisVideo: Unsatisfied link error. Directly loading native library .dll.

22:19:11
WARN / KinesisVideo: Unsatisfied link error. Directly loading native library libKinesisVideoProducerJNI.so.

22:19:11
WARN / KinesisVideo: Unsatisfied link error. Directly loading native library libKinesisVideoProducerJNI.dylib.

22:19:11
WARN / KinesisVideo: Unsatisfied link error. Directly loading native library libKinesisVideoProducerJNI.dll.

22:19:11
ERROR / KinesisVideo: 2018-06-02T22:19Z T1: EXCEPTION: UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unsatisfied link error. Loading native library KinesisVideoProducerJNI failed with java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no KinesisVideoProducerJNI in java.library.path: no KinesisVideoProducerJNI in java.library.path

22:19:11
com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.producer.ProducerException: Failed loading native library
```

how can I add/link native libraries to aws Lambda ?

the code written in java and I use eclipse to build/upload to AWS lambda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the problem by uploading the file to S3 Bucket,
then getting the file back as S3Object and saving it to `"/tmp/libKinesisVideoProducerJNI.so"` then loading it

```
S3Object libso = awsObject.getObject(s3Client, "bucket", "libKinesisVideoProducerJNI.so");

            File lib = awsObject.save(libso.getObjectContent(), "/tmp/libKinesisVideoProducerJNI.so");

            System.out.println("library file was saved to " + lib.getAbsolutePath());

            System.load(lib.getAbsolutePath());
```